# NOT IN clause in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm trying to restrain a selection using the NOT IN clause.

This is what i want to do :

```
SELECT name,id
 from "Schemas"."Paths" 
 where id not in(
   select  parent from "Schemas"."Paths"
   )
```

But this give me an empty table.

I've got 824 rows in this table and when i tried this :

```
SELECT name,id
 from "Schemas"."Paths" 
 where id in(
   select  parent from "Schemas"."Paths"
   )
```

I got a 182's rows table.

I'm missing something but what?

Comment: given that every node in a tree has to have a parent (except the root), you basically exclude EVERY node.  what are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I understand the confusion. parent is actually a column of my table "Paths"

Comment: yes, but that's basically saying "the sky is blue". you're selecting records from a table, and trying to exclude any of those records that have parents. since they ALL have parents, you exclude everything. You need to tell us what you're trying to do with this query, because as it's written now, it works perfectly, but obviously now the way you WANT it to. So tell us what you WANT it to do.

Comment: The scheme of my table is (id,name,parent) and it's describing an xml tree. Therefore the leafs of this tree don't appear in the parent column for this column is supposed to be the path through the curent node. Not sure if i'm clear. I'm trying to select all the leafs of my tree i.e. : the rows where id is never in the column parent

Comment: `NOT EXISTS( ... )` is the way to go. (and the checked answer is wrong)

Comment: Hum... if i checked this answer, it's because it works for me. The code sample didn't work but the explanation befor it did. But i'm sure NOT EXISTS would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely you have at least one null parent in your `Paths`. Depending on how you intend using the parents, either filter these out directly (e.g. with `WHERE parent IS NOT NULL`), or use a projection like `COALESCE` to map these to something which does exist:

```
SELECT name,id
 from Paths 
 where id not in (
   select COALESCE(parent, 0) from Paths
);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/3c204/4) showing how `NOT IN` returns zero rows when the sequence contains null.

Comment: I do have a null parent in my table. But parent is of type character varying and it seems to be a problem. I've got this : ERROR: COALESCE types character varying and integer cannot be matched

Solved with "where parent IS NOT NULL"
Thanks a lot